# openmp nested loop processing performance

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

Please consider following code:

```
void process(int N, int K, const vector<int>& data)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        //perform some processing based on data, N and K
    }
}

void solve(int N, int K, const vector<int>& data)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < K; ++j)
        {
            process(N, K, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Code above is executed with different size of each parameters.
N and K are in range 1 - 1000 (in most cases). Very often both are 1.
data.size() also varies a lot and is between 100 and 300 000.

The code above in most cases works great. The problem is if N or K are greater than ~100. e.g. K is 300 and data is not so large. e.g.: 1000. 
In such cases most of the time my program is waiting for waking up the omp threads. And if I disable omp then in such case the program is 2-3 times faster.

My question is - is it possible to somehow instrument omp to keep spinlocks when executing loops inside solve function ?
I have tried OMP_WAIT_POLICY Active and it solves the problem, but because of other reasons (it is small part of big application) I have to stay with Passive mode so far. Is there an other option to keep the threads Active for a while (or any other idea how to fix this issue)?

Edit:
According to @Gilles here is my full test program:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <omp.h>

std::atomic<int> cnt;

void process(int a, int b, std::vector<int>& d)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {
        //sample operation
        if (d[i] > a + b)
            ++cnt;
    }
}

void solve(int N, int K, std::vector<int>& d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < K; ++j)
        {
            process(i, j, d);
        }
    }
}

void RunTest(int numOfThreads, int N, int K, int arrSize)
{
    std::vector<int> s(arrSize);
    s[0] = s[10] = 1000;

    omp_set_num_threads(numOfThreads);
    cnt = 0;

    std::chrono::duration<double> minDiff = std::chrono::duration<double>{ 99999999 };
    for (int iters = 0; iters < 20; ++iters)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        solve(N, K, s);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
        if (diff < minDiff)
            minDiff = diff;
    }
    std::cout << "Time: " << minDiff.count() * 1000 << " ms \t\t" << "Threads: " << numOfThreads << " N: " << N << " K: " << K << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Large N*K" << std::endl;
    RunTest(6, 100, 100, 10000);
    RunTest(1, 100, 100, 10000);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Small N*K" << std::endl;
    RunTest(6, 1, 1, 1000000);
    RunTest(1, 1, 1, 1000000);
}
```

The results according to ACTIVE/PASSIVE wait policy (tested on MSVC 2019):

```
PASSIVE:
Large N*K
Time: 126.358 ms                Threads: 6 N: 100 K: 100
Time: 83.0023 ms                Threads: 1 N: 100 K: 100

Small N*K
Time: 0.194 ms                  Threads: 6 N: 1 K: 1
Time: 0.6687 ms                 Threads: 1 N: 1 K: 1

ACTIVE
Large N*K
Time: 20.8449 ms                Threads: 6 N: 100 K: 100
Time: 82.4809 ms                Threads: 1 N: 100 K: 100

Small N*K
Time: 0.1404 ms                 Threads: 6 N: 1 K: 1
Time: 0.6845 ms                 Threads: 1 N: 1 K: 1
```

As you can see in Passive mode when N*K is quite large the time is way bigger.

Comment: Would setting a `#pragma omp parallel` before the `i` loop of the `solve()` function, and an orphan `#pragma omp for` directive before the `i` loop of the `process()` function be sufficient to address your issue?

Comment: @Gilles I have tried this way, but then all threads execute `process` multiple times with the same parameters N,K. (Maybe I used this statement in a wrong way.)

Comment: could you please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Gilles, you are right I have used `#pragma omp parallel for` within process loop. There should be `pragma omp for`. Then the result is correct and the algorithm is way faster. (not as fast as ACTIVE option, but worth to apply in code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you MCVE, I did some tests and I believe there are some issues in the way your code is written.

1. You're using `std::atomic<int>` as type for your counter where the results are accumulated, and just increase it (atomically as a consequence). Although that is correct from a functional point of view, that is not a very efficient approach. Changing the counter to be a simple`int` and declaring it to be `reduction(+:cnt)` in the `parallel` region is much better.
2. You are creating your `parallel` regions inside the `N` x `K` loops. Moving the `parallel` directive upwards could potentially help. Then your former `#pragma omp parallel for` directive becomes a orphan `#pragma omp for` one.

So I've experiment a bit with these ideas and here is what I've got now (using 4 threads as I have 4 cores on my machine):

-Your version with passive policy:

```
Large N*K
Time: 74.4741 ms        Threads: 4 N: 100 K: 100
Time: 40.2336 ms        Threads: 1 N: 100 K: 100

Small N*K
Time: 0.151747 ms       Threads: 4 N: 1 K: 1
Time: 0.395791 ms       Threads: 1 N: 1 K: 1
```

-My version with passive policy:

```
Large N*K
Time: 35.1184 ms        Threads: 4 N: 100 K: 100
Time: 7.932 ms      Threads: 1 N: 100 K: 100

Small N*K
Time: 0.040216 ms       Threads: 4 N: 1 K: 1
Time: 0.082633 ms       Threads: 1 N: 1 K: 1
```

-Your version with active policy

```
Large N*K
Time: 16.3105 ms        Threads: 4 N: 100 K: 100
Time: 44.4862 ms        Threads: 1 N: 100 K: 100

Small N*K
Time: 0.110355 ms       Threads: 4 N: 1 K: 1
Time: 0.427118 ms       Threads: 1 N: 1 K: 1
```

-My version with active policy:

```
Large N*K
Time: 5.30402 ms        Threads: 4 N: 100 K: 100
Time: 9.57645 ms        Threads: 1 N: 100 K: 100

Small N*K
Time: 0.028136 ms       Threads: 4 N: 1 K: 1
Time: 0.094375 ms       Threads: 1 N: 1 K: 1
```

From that I'd say that:

1. The removal of the `std:atomic` and use of the `reduction(+)` instead does have a major effect and should be pursued
2. If the waiting policy has to be passive, then there's no point in going the multi-threaded route as single thread version is always faster than multi-threaded one in that configuration.

For the record, here is what the modified part looks like:

```
int cnt;

void process(int a, int b, std::vector<int>& d)
{
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:cnt)
    for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {
        //sample operation
        if (d[i] > a + b)
            ++cnt;
    }
}

void solve(int N, int K, std::vector<int>& d)
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < K; ++j)
        {
            process(i, j, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. In my real case I can't use reduction. But it is possible to further optimize your approach with `#pragma omp for reduction(+) nowait`. In this case `nowait` gives also great improvement for large N*K. Anyway everything is based on your initial solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

> or any other idea how to fix this issue?

When distributing computations to threads you want to have as big chunks as possible and as little synchronisation as possible. In your example you should rather parallelize the outer most loop. In your example it is not clear if `process` modifies `data`. It is passed as non-const, but assuming it is not modified, this is something I'd expect to perform better:

```
void solve(int N, int K, vector<int>& data)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < K; ++j)
        {
            process(N, K, data);
        }
    } // <-- threads have to wait here until all are finished
}
```

(simplistic) Rationale: spawning and gathering threads takes time and introduces overhead. In your code you have that overhead `N*K` times. If you parallelize the outermost loop you have that overhead once.

Comment: Thanks, I have marked data as const. I agree with your statement, but in this case size of N and K is very often 1 (or smaller than number of threads). I wouldn't like to loose omp optimization in "process" function in such cases.

Comment: @AdamF I would prefer if you dont change your question once you got answers. Now my answer is outdated and would have to fix it. Anyhow, then make two different versions of `solve` that call different versions of `process` one with parallel `solve`, sequential `process` and one the other way around, then pick one or the other depending on the sizes. Would make a fun exercise to see where the turning point is. I am a bit jealous ;)

Comment: In such case I can remove loops over N and K completely and in `process` iterate over 0 .. data.size() * N * K. But it makes the code ugly and much more difficult to maintain, and then I need also to compute the indexes correctly.

Comment: @AdamF what you write is not apparent from the code you posted. If you can flatten the loops into one, you should have done this right from the start. Also I fail to see how this would introcude uglyness or any difficulties in maintaining the code, what is the problem with computing indices?